# Creating tags in subfolder when adding a new tag on the parent folder

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

So im trying to add new tags on my subfolders/files when updating or adding a new tag on the parent folder, im using this code but the tagNodeRef seems to not have the correct information, i cant debugg it since i dont have acess to the aplication itself and cant turn on the javaScript debugger too, any sort of help? thx

```
var tags = space.properties["cm:taggable"];
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length ; i++){
var tagNodeRef = tags[i];
document.addAspect("cm:taggable");
document.addTag(tagNodeRef);
```

Comment: Consider installing the JavaScript Console (https://github.com/share-extras/js-console). It allows you to run server-side JavaScript against Alfresco interactively, includes code completion, and links to docs.

Comment: Yes, i tried that but didnt have the files of the server to install the console

Comment: If you have Java and Maven you can fire up a test server easily using the Alfresco SDK. Then you'd have a local server to test with. You can also add the JavaScript Console as a dependency to that so that when you start it up, it is installed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think addTag(tag) takes string as the argument and you are passing noderef to it.
can you try this

```
var tags = space.properties["cm:taggable"];
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length ; i++){
  var tagNodeRef = tags[i];
  document.addAspect("cm:taggable");
  document.addTag(tagNodeRef.properties["cm:name"]);
}
```

Comment: man, how can i refer to the elements inside? not just the folders

Comment: i cant get your question, can you explain the requirement please

Comment: I just got it by myself, I just wanted to do it to the documents inside a second folder too, so I just needed to press the execute for subfolders button.